# Realtime database clould function : why is this query returning null?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a mailbox table that has a name field, that I want to update/insert the name when it changes in the user table. Query is always returning null.

[image: mailbox table]

In the user change table listener :

```
exports.updateMailboxes = functions.database.ref('/users/{userId}')
  .onUpdate((change, context) => {
  const rec = change.after.val();

  functions.logger.log('updateMailboxes check ', String(context.params.userId));

  return admin.database().ref('/mailbox')
    .orderByChild('toID')
    .equalTo(String(context.params.userId))
    .once('value', (snapshot) => {
      functions.logger.log('updateMailboxes ', JSON.stringify(snapshot.val()));
      snapshot.forEach((child) => {
        functions.logger.log('updateMailboxes child ', JSON.stringify(child.val()));
        child.ref.update({name: rec.username});
      });
  });
});
```

I even hardcoded a value in equalTo like this :

```
.equalTo("f3EXPNBjuecmdViCKZF1FduTrXd2")
```

it still returns null.

orderByChild by itself works.

I tried also to query by key, as per Dharmaraj's answer :

```
exports.updateMailboxes = functions.database.ref('/users/{userId}')
  .onUpdate((change, context) => {
  const rec = change.after.val();

  functions.logger.log('updateMailboxes check ', String(context.params.userId));

  return admin.database().ref('/mailbox/{ownerID}')
    .orderByKey()
    .equalTo(context.params.userId)
    .once('value').then((snapshot) => {
      functions.logger.log('updateMailboxes ', JSON.stringify(snapshot.val()));
      snapshot.forEach((child) => {
        functions.logger.log('updateMailboxes child ', JSON.stringify(child.val()));
        child.ref.update({name: rec.username});
      });
  });
});
```

And it still returns null.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the purpose of mailbox? If you are building an inbox of messages, wouldn't you show the most recent message sent to both users, regardless of who sent it?

Comment: Hello, yes of course - the first record shows to user1, the second record shows to user2 - "toID" should actually be "otherID"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the value is same as the key of that node so you can use [orderByKey](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sort_data):

```
firebase.database().ref(`/mailbox/{senderID}`).orderByKey().equalTo(context.params.userId).once("value").then((snap) => {
  console.log(snap.val());
})
```

As per your database structure, you would have to mention the senderID in the `ref`. You may have to store the IDs users who have sent an email to a specific user. If someone sends a mail to toID 'myUserID1', then you will have to store the sender's ID in a separate node.

When your cloud functions runs, fetch that node first so you know which nodes you are supposed to updated the name in mailbox node.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I tried this and it still returns null, I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at this query:

```js
admin.database().ref('/mailbox')
  .orderByChild('toID')
  .equalTo(String(context.params.userId))
```

What you are asking is for the children of `/mailbox` to be sorted by their value of `toID`. As each child under `/mailbox` doesn't have a value for `"toID"`, the query uses a value of `null` for each of these children (see below) and then sorts them lexicographically by key (more information: [Sorting with `orderByChild`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#orderbychild)). This is why you get no results when you change the query to find results where `"toID"` is the desired user.

```json
{
  "mailbox": {
    "KG0XjVNQ2Ka1offWN2VH3YbNqNx1": {
      "gMVleaAuVbhGnROsBBkMS6gFum62": {
        // message data
      },
      "Wde7E2ONDFfolUHGFb5OipDgMpN2": {
        // message data
      },
      // "toID": null
    },
    "gMVleaAuVbhGnROsBBkMS6gFum62": {
      "KG0XjVNQ2Ka1offWN2VH3YbNqNx1": {
        // message data
      },
      "Wde7E2ONDFfolUHGFb5OipDgMpN2": {
        // message data
      },
      // "toID": null
    },
    "Wde7E2ONDFfolUHGFb5OipDgMpN2": {
      "KG0XjVNQ2Ka1offWN2VH3YbNqNx1": {
        // message data
      },
      "gMVleaAuVbhGnROsBBkMS6gFum62": {
        // message data
      },
      // "toID": null
    }
  }
}
```

With your current database structure, you will need to fetch all of `/mailbox` and then sift through the data to find messages that target the desired user. Because the `"toID"` has the same value as that node's key in your current structure, we can search for nodes that have the given ID as its child. This can be done using the following query:

```
admin.database().ref(`/mailbox`)
  .orderByChild(context.params.userId)
  .startAfter(null) // skip nodes that don't have this user
```

**Important Note:** This has terrible performance at scale with many users. Even though you could create an index for each user using `".indexOn"`, this is impractical.

To improve the performance of such an operation, you will need to store information about who has sent the given user a message.

```
{
  "mailboxReceivedFrom": {
    "KG0XjVNQ2Ka1offWN2VH3YbNqNx1": {       // <- user ID who received the message
      "gMVleaAuVbhGnROsBBkMS6gFum62": true, // <- user ID who sent the message
      "Wde7E2ONDFfolUHGFb5OipDgMpN2": true
    },
    "gMVleaAuVbhGnROsBBkMS6gFum62": {
      "KG0XjVNQ2Ka1offWN2VH3YbNqNx1": true,
      "Wde7E2ONDFfolUHGFb5OipDgMpN2": true,
    },
    "Wde7E2ONDFfolUHGFb5OipDgMpN2": {
      "KG0XjVNQ2Ka1offWN2VH3YbNqNx1": true,
      "gMVleaAuVbhGnROsBBkMS6gFum62": true
    }
    // Note: You could store the timestamp of the most recent message instead for sorting
  }
}
```

```
const userId = String(context.params.userId);
const username = rec.username;

return admin.database().ref('/mailboxReceivedFrom')
  .child(userId)
  .once('value')
  .then((querySnapshot) => {
    // prepare object to hold updates
    const pendingUpdates = {};

    // for each child, queue updating the username
    querySnapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
      const path = childSnapshot.key + "/" + userId + "/name";
      pendingUpdates[path] = username;
    })

    // make changes to the database all at once
    return admin.database.ref("/mailbox")
      .update(pendingUpdates);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error("Failed to apply username change for user #" + userId, err);
  });
```